# Slick PHP based image manager for managing user profile images

Tags: php, jquery

I'm just throwing this out there as I'm plodding my way through creating a Member Photo album on a site i'm working on, where they can login and upload their photos to a personal gallery. I want this to be nice and lightweight, but still slick and "modern" with a modal based interface for the user. I'm surprised though that there is seemingly nothing open source out there which fits the bill - I've done a few searches on Google to no avail and can't seem to find anything. Lots of bloated photo galleries out there but nothing looks like it has been developed using more recent technologies.

Is anyone aware of anything which might suit what I'm looking for? I'm fully prepared to try and code it myself but I'd be delighted if I didn't have to! Pure laziness you might say, but there's no point reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/)